# SSIS 2012 Execute package issue - not able to view messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have been executing SSIS packages from SQL Server Management Studio (that have been deployed through Data Tools 2012) and then clicking view executions to see all the messages about the execution of the packages.

Today the package just hangs and after about 30 minutes, comes up with a cancelled status and there are no messages visible when I click view messages.

When I run the following query, seems like every time I run the package it gets a deadlock. e.g.

```
  SELECT * FROM SYSPROCESSES where blocked > 0
```

I get:

> blocked: 151, waittype: 0x0008, lastwaittype: LCK_M_IX, waitresource:
>   TAB: 7:821577965:0, status: suspended, program name:SSIS ISServerExec,
>   cmd insert   , hostprocess 6556.

I am thinking this could be because the service pack hasn't been applied, the SQL Server version is 11.0.2100.60, but was wondering why this happens all the time now whereas I have been executing packages on this server for weeks.

Is it possible to resolve this without applying the service pack, or is this the only way to fix the issue?

Thanks for any help.

Regards, Rob

Comment: Use this to work out the object it is waiting on: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic16430-5-1.aspx. LCK_M_IX is 'intent exclusive' lock. Try unticking 'table lock' in your package or restart the SQL Server to clear out any hung processes that might be locking the table.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I restarted the database and now the messages appear for the package. regards, Rob